# Android: My XML with a selector is not well-formed while styling a button?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

I just tried this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). I saved that code in res/color/hover.xml but I always get this error message and Eclipse won't compile my project with this xml. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector> <!-- Error Message -->
```

**Error parsing XML:** not well-formed (invalid token) hover.xml /MmAndroid/res/color line 8 Android AAPT Problem

The only thing I might not have done is following. I don't know how to do that:

> **compiled resource datatype:** Resource
>   pointer to a ColorStateList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put this xml file inside the drawable folder. not in res/color

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! How stupid, that they have such major mistakes in their examples on android.com!

Answer (score 0):

> How stupid, that they have such major mistakes in their examples on
>   android.com!

It's not a mistake at-all.
You can define selectors for text or for backgrounds. Lets say you want your text to be green, if `state_check="true"`. What will you do then? Lay a background behind?

No. You will probably create an xml file with selectors for color-attributes. And reference `textColor="@color/MYNEWCOLORXML"` .... ét voilà.